# Code coverage with MSTest & Jenkins

Tags: c#, mstest

I am executing my UnitTestCases using MSTest in Jenkins. How do I create a code coverage report for those UnitTestCases? Can MSTest itself generate any HTML reports?

I looked for **coverage.trx** but was not able to find anything. Is there a feature for MSTest to generate codecoverage in C#?